# Invalid parameter - AdCreative ( facebook-marketing-api)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

During the creation of an AdCreative in the facebook marketing api (using the PHP sdk), I get the "*Invalid Parameter*" error. According to the graph-api (see below), the error is happening because I am trying to create an AdCreative using an app that is in development mode.

Since I am making a *Proof of Concept*, I doubt that my app will be approved for the *ads_management* permission (which I need for the creation of an AdCreative).

**Is there a way to create the AdCreative (and consequently an Ad) using the facebook-marketing-api using my app (in development mode)?**

*if not, is there **any other way** to do so?*

---

When I put the application in "public" mode, I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#294) Managing advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission for ads_management","type":"OAuthException","code":294,"fbtrace_id":"AHZ4vUXzCv+"}}
```

I am using the official Creative guide by facebook to create the AdCreative: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api

I am currently using the following code to create the AdCreative

```php
// campaign creation (objective -> reach)
// adset creation
// adimage creation

$creativeFields = [];

$creativeParams = [
    'name' => $validatedRequest['creative_name'],
    'object_story_spec' => [
        'page_id' => $page_id,
        'link_data' => [
            'image_hash' => $image->{AdImageFields::HASH},
            'link' => "https://facebook.com/{$page_id}",
            'message' => 'THIS IS THE DEFAULT MESSAGE FOR AD CREATIVES - [[THIS IS VERSION 2]]',
        ],
    ],
];

$creativeId = (new AdAccount($id))->createAdCreative($creativeFields, $creativeParams)
                                  ->exportAllData();
```

When I try to create the AdCreative using the graph-api (using curl) I get the following JSON response:

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid Parameter", "type":"OAuthException", "code":100, "error_subcode":1885183, "is_transient":false, "error_user_title":"Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode", "error_user_msg":"Ads creative post was created by an app that is in development mode. It must be in public to create this ad.", "fbtrace_id":"GzpSaGkDlNa"}}
```

Comment: With a user account that has a role in the app you should be able to grant `ads_management` even before it is reviewed.

Comment: @04FS I am able to grant _ads_management_ when my app is in development mode **only**. If I set the status to _live_, I cannot grant _ads_management_ unless I send the application for review.

Comment: At least in Graph API Explorer I am still able to select that permission for an app that is in live mode (and does not have it reviewed), and `/me/permissions` shows it as granted afterwards.

Comment: I cannot see the **ad_management** permission in the Graph Api. Am i missing something?

Comment: would check out the following question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56338825/facebook-marketing-api-ad-creatives

Comment: hi @Jean-SébastienLaurent Did you ever manage to fix this issue?