# Facebook Marketing API ad creatives

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the facebook application with approved `ads_read`, `manage_pages` `ads_management`, `business_management` and `Ads Management Standard Access` permissions.
I can create Ad campaign, ad set and can upload asset to Facebook via Facebook Marketing API.

But when I try to create ad creative, with `/adcreatives` request, I get Error with message:

> (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.

The example of `curl` request:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_<account_id>/adcreatives?access_token=<access_token_here>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Host: graph.facebook.com' \
  -d 'call_to_action_type=USE_APP&actor_id=<page_id>&object_type=APPLICATION&status=active&name=hello&title=foo&page_id=<page_id>&id=act_<account id>&image_hash=fb1a69e0965076e791183ac82c9f7417'
```

I've tried making requests with app token, with page token and with user token (which was allowed in FB Business manager).
I've also tried with sandbox account and it's token
Every service (app, facebook page and user) connected with business account in business manager and have admin (max) permissions.
I've tried to send data in body with JSON request, I've tried to send data as x-www-form-urlencoded.
I've tried using plain http requests and tried with [facebook-nodejs-business-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/facebook-nodejs-business-sdk)
But still no success.

So, the question is, **what is the correct AD Creative create request and what permissions does my app need to perform such task?**

P.S. I've also asked a few questions on Facebook Developers forum and got no solution. [q1](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/676877452752816/), [q2](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2345592909028882/), [q3](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2225103570860725/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your input is malformed (although the returned errors from FB usually never indicate as much).

The main issue that I see is that the creative information is not being passed through the `object_story_spec` parameter. The type of creative you are making is passed in through this object along with the necessary parameters, which would be `photo_data` in your case.

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_<ACT_ID>/adcreatives?access_token=<TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Host: graph.facebook.com' \
  -d 'link_url=<URL>&name=<CREATIVE_NAME>&object_type=PAGE&object_story_spec={page_id:<PAGE_ID>,photo_data:{image_hash:<HASH>,caption:<CAPTION>}}'
```

You will probably need to add or remove parameters as needed, but the above request worked for me.

In terms of permissions, here is what I had:

[image]

Some additional references:
[Ad Creative](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative)
[Object Story Spec](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-object-story-spec/)
[Photo Data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-photo-data/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've followed your advice and now the problem is that I receive ad creative id from facebook, but can't find it on Facebook Page or in Ads Manager. Do you know where Facebook store ad creative?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to view the creative on the ui unless it's attached to an ad. You'll have to pass that creative id into the parameters when you make an ad.

Comment: But if you want to preview it not on ads manager, you can use the generate preview endpoint on the api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/generatepreview/v3.3

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel that with your help I'm getting closer to the finish. Don't you mind if I ask one more question? It looks like I successfully create ad creative, and now I try to upload ad. Fields: `{name, campaign_id, adset_id, creative: {creative_id}, status}`. The problem is, I'm getting error > "Object Store URL does not match promoted object: Please ensure that the object store URL associated with your ad creative matches the object store URL set on your promoted object." ;
Event though, in ad set create and ad creative create I mention the same object_store_url

Comment: Might be better to make a separate question, not sure what parameters you're passing when you're making the creative. Are you using the link_data or photo_data format? You should also be passing only one of `object_story_spec` or `object_url`.

Comment: Here is my second question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446925/correct-way-to-create-ad-with-facebook-marketing-api I will be very grateful if you help me :)