# Request to promote iOS App in Facebook via Marketing API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I have the facebook application with approved `ads_read, manage_pages ads_management, business_management and Ads Management Standard Access permissions`.
I can create `Ad campaign`, `ad set` and can upload `asset` to Facebook via Facebook Marketing API.

I create ad set with such parameters:

```
{
      name: 'adset_name',
      campaign_id: '<campaign_id>',
      lifetime_spend_cap: 11000,
      promoted_object: {
        application_id: '<fb_app_id>',
        object_store_url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/app/<my_app>',
        page_id: '<page_id>',
      },
      billing_event: 'IMPRESSIONS',
      optimization_goal: 'APP_INSTALLS',
      bid_amount: 20000,
      targeting: {
        age_min: 20,
        age_max: 25,
        genders: [1],
        locales: [6],
         user_os: ['iOS_ver_11.0_and_above'],
        geo_locations: {
          countries: ["US"],
        },
        excluded_geo_locations: {
          countries: ["GB"],
        },
        publisher_platforms: 'facebook',
        facebook_positions: ['feed'],
      },
      device_platforms: 'mobile',
      pacing_type: 'standard',
      status: 'PAUSED',
      end_time: '2019-07-30 23:59:59-07:00',
    };
```

I create ad creative with such fields:

```
{
    object_type: 'APPLICATION',
    status: 'ACTIVE',
    name: 'hello',
    title: 'foo',
    object_story_spec: {
      page_id: '<facebook page id associated with app>',
      photo_data: {
        image_hash: asset_hash,
        caption: 'Just image',
      },
    },
    application_id: '<app store app id>',
    object_store_url: 'https://itunes.apple.com/app/<my app same as application_id>',
  }
```

The problem is, when I try to create ad with parameters:

```
{
    name: 'Heyyy',
    campaign_id,
    adset_id,
    creative: {
      creative_id,
    },
    status: 'PAUSED',
 }
```

I got error

> Object Store URL does not match promoted object: Please ensure that the object store URL associated with your ad creative matches the object store URL set on your promoted object.

If I look to my Facebook business manager -> Ads manager, I see created `ad set` which is linked to app, page and iOS application.
Everything looks like if I create ad set by my own, not script.
So, I'm pretty sure that `ad set` creates correctly.
But I can't figure out how to create `ad creative` to make it work.

I have this problem for 2 weeks from now, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56338825/facebook-marketing-api-ad-creatives) is my question about ad creative error.

P.S. Here is links to my questions on facebook community forum, if it could help to clear the situation [link](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2583299445091409/), [link](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/676877452752816/), [link](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2345592909028882/), [link](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2225103570860725/)

Comment: Try adding a link_url on Ad Creative that matches the adset: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative

Comment: @Abundance, thank you. I've tried with adding `link_url` and `object_atore_url` pointing to the same url as in adset. I've also tried to use url from /advertisable_applications request with link, associated with app, but no success.
Do you have some working example of `curl` request for ad set creation and ad?

Comment: I haven't made ads to promote an application, but it seems as if they are slightly different. I would take a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/promoted-object/v3.3

Comment: The problem seems that the object_story_spec is promoting a page (hence page_id), while the adset is promoting an app. Under the creative parameters, there is an `object_id` parameter where you can enter the id of the promoted object.

Comment: @Abundance, sorry for the silly question, but where can I find `promoted_object_id`? I mean, I create adset with `promoted_object` parameters, specifically: `application_id` and `object_store_url`. In response I get adset id. If I use this adset id as object_id in my ad creation, I get > No Promoted Object: There was no valid promoted object found. This can happen if you didn't specify a promoted object, or specified an object that we cannot promote.

Comment: not too sure myself, did you try the app id? I would also check the settings of your facebook app and see. The documentation states: "The object_store_url MUST be associated with that application. You can configure this on developers.facebook.com under your application settings." Maybe the same applies for a `promoted_object_id`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your URL is different:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/<my_app> – in adset

https://itunes.apple.com/app/<my-app-same-as-application_id> – in creative.

It seems you missed `us` part?

Comment: @IvanPomortsev thank you. I've tried both links, and still no result. Need to update my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

8 days past, and I finally found out how to make it.
You can find info on this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/mobile-app-ads)

And now my AD Creative params looks like this:

```
{
    object_type: 'APPLICATION',
    status: 'ACTIVE',
    name: 'hello',
    title: 'foo',
    object_story_spec: {
      page_id: '<fb_page_id>',
      link_data: {
        call_to_action: {
          type: 'INSTALL_MOBILE_APP',
          value: {
            link: 'https://itunes.apple.com/app/<app>',
          },
        },
        image_hash: 'image hash',
        link: 'https://itunes.apple.com/app/<app>',
        message: 'Message',
      },
    },
  }
```